# Spring 3 IOC annotation

Tags: spring, autowired

I have the following packages hierarchy

 -org.bmark

   --dao

    --- implementations

    --- interfaces

   --services

    --- implementations

    --- interfaces

This is my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This is part of my ApplicationContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.bmark.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.bmark.services"/>
```

I have A UserDAO and a ContentTypeDAO (Both have implementations). I also have a UserService and a ContentTypeService (Both have implementations). The services class have the @Service annotation.
The UserDAO is @Autowired into the implementation of the UserServiceImpl and everything works good. The issue is that the ContentTypeDAO is also @Autowired into the ContentTypeServiceImpl but when i start the server i get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentTypeServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.bmark.dao.intefaces.ContentTypeDAO org.bmark.services.implementations.ContentTypeServiceImpl.contentTypeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.bmark.dao.intefaces.ContentTypeDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}<br/>
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.bmark.dao.intefaces.ContentTypeDAO org.bmark.services.implementations.ContentTypeServiceImpl.contentTypeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.bmark.dao.intefaces.ContentTypeDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}<br/>
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.bmark.dao.intefaces.ContentTypeDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Why am i getting this exception on my ContentTypeDAO and not getting it with my UserDAO?
How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.bmark.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.bmark.services"/>
```

with

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.bmark.dao, org.bmark.services"/>
```

I'm not entirely sure if the context supports multiple `component-scan` definitions or if perhaps one is overriding the other.